# Is 52C too hot for this LED?

Tags: led

I got three UFO / Saucer LEDs from China. According to the seller on ebay they are produced by Ranpo, but the LEDs are as unbranded as it gets. They are also, according to the seller, 30W - but the LED itself is silent on that as well.

Anyway, the LEDs get somewhat hot. I measured 52C on the top "golden" area. Is that too hot, or is it fine for this wattage?

[image]

Comment: Seems reasonable.

Comment: you want to keep them below 70-80 for max longevity. the actual COBs might be a lot hotter than the surface, so you might actually be borderline. if you can get a probe closer the junction, the data would be more meaningful.

Comment: @dandavis that 52C is on the air side of the heatsink, the LEDs themselves will be a tad hotter than that. Seems about right.

Comment: Any temperature will work for your LED, even 100 Celsius. HOWEVER, the hotter the LED the shorter the life.  So, how long do you want your LED to live? Longs answer short, 52C on the outside of the lamp seems A LOT to me considering that the lamp body is made from plastic!

Comment: You stated that the lamp body is made from plastic. This is BAD! There is no real thermal dissipation. I expect the LED temperature to be 85C in this case, probably more! Drill some holes into the body to let the air circulate. You will be amazed to see how much difference those holes will make! Make the holes on the white (transparent) body and also on the golden body to let the air circulate from below to the top, around the LEDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern COB LEDs can operate up to 80C but anything cooler will improve the life expectancy of your LED.

In your case the LED module is probably mounted in way that it can dissipate its heat to the metal casing so if the metal casing is 52C the LED itself will be slightly warmer but most probably still within its operating range.

If those LEDs were very expensive it might be worth considering cooling a little for a longer life. But cooling those with for example a fan might cost more (buying the fan and running it) compared to replacing the LED a little earlier.
Chances are that the fan will break down before the LED.

PS : found that these use 5730 SMD LEDs which also have a operating temperature up to 80C

Comment: The LED "bulbs" were USD 2.80 each, so I don't think any extra purchases to extend the lifetime will be worthwhile. The casing is entirely plastic by the way, no metal heat sink.

Comment: I have seen several pictures of a identical lamp and it had the typical white PCB with nicely spaced 5730 LEDs. Although it wasn't clear what power version was shown so clearance between LEDs might be less. I suspect that the PCB has a thin aluminium back plate for some heat dissipation.

Answer (score 2):

Reliability is ~doubled for every 10'C reduction above room temp . unless there is a process/design flaw.

It's "Watts on the junction in temp that counts.

Tjcn = Pd x ['C/W] on the thermal resistance interfaces between internal chip junction to the ambient hot surface.  Lumen ratings of chips are often done at 85'C junction but it is up to the Luminaire design to add the cost of making a low thermal resistance to the ambient surface.  It could a few 'C/W above the outside surface temp in the junction unless attention details with copper, extreme coplanarity and grease under pressure.

Comment: I know that a certain level of knowledge should be expected from users on this site, but would you mind adding a simplified summary of that answer for "the rest of us"?

Comment: If I had a magic wand I might guess the junction is 90~105'C.  In a well designed product that costs more in thermal mass (copper 99.99's silver epoxy,  vortex fins, etc.  Inside chip may be 60~70'C like your CPU.  So if the design and process is flawless it will last long if it were cooler inside. Outside we cant tell.  Put it this way, if your Quad core heatsink feels only slightly hot while running at 70'C inside, this LED is could be running about 120'C inside. ouch.

Comment: But will the temperature be dangerous in terms of e.g. fire - and not so much the durability?

Comment: safe , cheap and good. last long needs a crystal ball/// or sound engineering design

Comment: This temperature is still a lot less compared to a conventional bulb with the same light output!

Comment: Tungsten goes above 2400'C, question is more about reliability of LED than safety of fingers

Comment: @Tony, in his recent comment he was concerned about fire and other hazards. That's why I compared it to a conventional bulb (for this purpose only)

Comment: I see that.   too bad he implied otherwise in his question.  "Is that too hot, or is it fine for this wattage?" almost bud smoking hot inside

Comment: @DanielP yes, i was actually mostly concernced with the general safety (e.g. fire) I'm just a little extra concerned about these unbranded cheap china LEDs, although I still can't resist them as they are so cheap. I don't really care if they die after a couple of years (although not a sustainable way of going about buying goods in general). My "is it fine for this wattage" question was probably a bit misleading on that account...

Comment: Buying LED lamps can sometimes be a problem that even if you try to buy a good expensive brand you mostly still get the exact same cheap China LED. The trick is to find the right Chinese Lamp. Looking for an existing review on youtube can be handy (much thanks to people like Dave Jones, BigClive ... etc). My biggest concern with Chinese lamps is electrocution, never ever touch the single LEDs on a uncovered lamp because it's likely to have mains voltage on some LEDs.

Comment: @DanielP thanks for your advise. I've intentionally stayed away of the exposed LED lamps as they just seems very "unfinished". Appreciate your note about single LEDs having main voltage - contrary to what this answer on another question of mine says : https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/31027/16798.

Comment: He is right that the voltage drop over a single LED is low but the voltage of one side of the LED to earth can be close or equal to mains voltage (there are some videos on youtube showing those dangers). If you don't have a RCD you might opt to install one to keep you and especially others safe (wife and/or kids who might be less careful). Here in Belgium a whole house RCD of 300mA is mandatory.

Comment: @DanielP yes, RCDs are mandatory up here in the very north of Europe as well - so I've got an 300mA RCD installed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually an LED's temperature is related to its power rating. At 100% of full power a bank of LED's can get very hot so 52c is not unusual.

However you can expect them to fail after 3 to 5 years of continuous use. Drop the power to 80%, and the temperature drops and the life expectancy goes up a lot.

At 50% of full power an LED should run for 50 years continuously. At 10% of full power they can run for hundreds of years. Do your best to keep them cool if you want a long life span.

Consider using a buck transformer to drop the voltage 10% to 20%. They will still be very bright but last much longer, assuming ambient temperature is around 25C.

Comment: What options do I have to drop the voltage when this is a LED "bulb" with an E27 socket. Isn't that something the producer should have taken care of for me, ensuring that the LEDS do not run at 100% but rather 80%?